# how to delete appended element using remove

Tags: button, append

i have a simple code that has 2 divs. one div consists one button called "add".  When its clicked, that will add other button in the second div . When you click any button in the 2nd div, it suppose to delete itself. as you can see in the code below, i am adding buttons in the second div using append. That's where my question comes. The code works if the delete button is already in the div. (meaning it will delete when its clicked). However buttons that are appended dont delete themselves. How do i make the buttons appended to delete themselves when clicked?

```
<title>AutoSuggestion using  Ajax, Jquery and PHP</title>

<script src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){


            $('#add').click(function(){
                var return_value = "appended button (click to delete me)";
                $('.seconddiv').append('<button class ="remove">'+return_value+'</button>'); 


            });
            $( '.remove' ).click(function() {
              $( this ).remove();

            });

});


</script>
```

```
<div class="firstdiv"><button id ="add" >add</button></div>
<div class="seconddiv"><button class ="remove" >click to delete me</button></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a rebinding issue

http://jsfiddle.net/87pt31La/

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    //intial call on load
    bindFunc()

    $('#add').click(function(){
        var return_value = "appended button (click to delete me)";
        $('.seconddiv').append('<button class ="remove">'+return_value+'</button>'); 
         bindFunc()
    });

    //any Js code that needs to be rebinded
    function bindFunc(){
        $( '.remove' ).click(function() {
              $( this ).remove();
        });
    }


});
```

When you add new html it isn't binded to the JS, so you have to rebind it.

Comment: thank you so much. this took me 5 hours yesterday. i was driving me crazy. thanks:)

Answer (score 0):

You can change your click event handler to attach to document instead.

```
$( document).on("click", ".remove",function() {
      $( this ).remove();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/q56odb3r/

Comment: thank you so much. this took me 5 hours yesterday. i was driving me crazy. thanks:)